# Difference between cgal and cgal-cpp

Tags: anaconda, cgal

I am currently trying to install some packages for colmap according to https://colmap.github.io/install.html. But as I work in a conda environment, I try to install cgal using conda.

To me it is not really clear however which is the correct pendant to libcgal-dev in conda.
I found that there is a package on the conda-forge channel called cgal and one called cgal-cpp.

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between those two packages?

Since I got conflicts for the former, I installed the second one and thus, I am not sure if that contains all files that the libcgal-dev contains or if I still miss some files.

Answer (score 0):

I think `cgal-cpp` contains all the usual C++ headers, while `cgal` contains the [Python bindings](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings).